# Mysql case join query assistance

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a query which gets all columns and a case column which denotes availablity, however I need to include a one to many relationship in the mix and it's messing with my head.

My query without the relationship:

```
SELECT storage_rooms.*,
    CASE
        WHEN release_date <= CURDATE() THEN 1
        WHEN release_date <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN release_date
        ELSE 0 
    END AS available
FROM storage_rooms
```

Which is fine and returns something like this:

[image]

Now I need to check if it is already booked.
To give you an idea of what I'm thinking (doesn't work):

```
SELECT storage_rooms.*,
    (SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN release_date <= CURDATE() OR orders.status_id IN (3, 4) THEN 1
        WHEN release_date <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN release_date
        ELSE 0 
    END AS available
    FROM storage_rooms
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders
    ON storage_rooms.id = orders.storage_room_id)
FROM storage_rooms
```

I gather I might need another subquery with a groupBy?
I don't find joins super intuitive and I'm a bit lost so any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: Can you be more precise on "doesn't work": is there a SQL error? If no, what are the results and how do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: I'm getting a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" which I guess makes sense without a group by.

Comment: I need it to make the 'available' column '1' if the status_id on order is 3 or 4. I don't think I'm even near the actual solution to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure it will work but you can try this:

```
SELECT storage_rooms.*,
    CASE
        WHEN release_date <= CURDATE() OR availibility.order_status_id IN (3, 4) THEN 1
        WHEN release_date <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN release_date
        ELSE 0 
    END AS available
FROM storage_rooms
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT id AS order_id, status_id AS order_status_id, storage_room_id AS order_storage_room_id
          FROM orders WHERE status_id IN (3, 4)
          GROUP BY storage_room_id
    ) availibility
    ON (storage_rooms.id = availibility.order_storage_room_id)
```

The thing here is that the `LEFT JOIN` is adding to the results the columns needed to check your availability. But the trick is you need a subquery so that the table joined contains only one entry for each room or else the results are duplicated. The subquery must be limited to the positive matches you want to take in consideration with a `WHERE`, because the `GROUP BY` will only keep the first row found and you don't want this information lost in the grouping.

FROM OP'S COMMENTS THE FINAL QUERY IS:

```
SELECT storage_rooms.*,
    CASE
        WHEN release_date <= CURDATE() OR aggregate.order_status_id IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN release_date <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN release_date
        ELSE 0
    END AS available
FROM storage_rooms
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT storage_room_id, order_status_id
        FROM orders WHERE order_status_id IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY storage_room_id, order_status_id
    ) aggregate
    ON storage_rooms.id = aggregate.storage_room_id
```

Comment: It's the query for a datatable.js table so I need all the storage_rooms that way I can take advantage of searching & ordering etc..

Comment: @DerpyMongoose OK I see better what you want, I edited the answer: `LEFT JOIN` will add all the `orders` data along with what is coming from `storage_rooms` when the ids correspond, and you should now be able to use `orders.status_id` in the `CASE`

Comment: I still need to group by storage_rooms.id somewhere I think. I'm getting duplicates for every order.

Comment: @DerpyMongoose You're right, now it should be better, if it works i'll update the answer with some details

Comment: Thanks I reached the right query based on your answer, I realize now that it was more fiddly than I thought and I didn't provide enough information to get a perfect answer.

Comment: SELECT storage_rooms.*,
    CASE
     WHEN release_date <= CURDATE() OR aggregate.order_status_id IS NULL THEN 1
      WHEN release_date <= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN release_date
      ELSE 0
    END AS available
FROM storage_rooms
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT storage_room_id, order_status_id
 FROM orders
 WHERE order_status_id IN (1, 2)
 GROUP BY storage_room_id, order_status_id) aggregate
ON storage_rooms.id = aggregate.storage_room_id